# CSS Media queries do not work at all

Tags: css, wordpress, themes, media

I've searched the internet back and forth a few times and I simply cannot understand what I seem to do wrong when using media queries in CSS. Some background information: I am using a wordpress theme called "Sela" and created a child theme for it, this is my style.css for the child theme:

```html
/*
Theme Name: Sela Child
Theme URI: https://wordpress.com/themes/sela/
Template: sela
Author: Automattic
Author URI: https://wordpress.com/themes/
Description: Sela is not your typical business theme. Vibrant, bold, and clean, with lots of space for large images, this theme will look great on all devices, from desktop to mobile.
Tags: blog,custom-background,custom-colors,custom-menu,featured-images,full-width-template,microformats,right-sidebar,rtl-language-support,sticky-post,translation-ready,two-columns
Version: 1.0.15.1473287968
Updated: 2016-09-08 00:39:28

*/

.site-footer {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 background-color: #0071bc;
    border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    color: #fff;
 
}
.main-navigation .menu > li > a::after {
  content: none;
}

button,
input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"],
#infinite-handle span {
 background-color: #0071bc;
}
.site-title {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 width: 55%;
}

@media screen and ((max-width:1024px) {
body {
 background: #04d056;
}
```

Then this is the head of my header.php:

```html
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

I really am absolutely clueless, right now I am trying to change the background to green, but that doesn't work at all! I've tried everything! Please help me out of my misery

Comment: You have a syntax error. You're saying `((max-width:1024px)` when you need to say `(max-width:1024px)`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ratsewaa/)

Answer (score 1):

Two issues in your media query:

1. Using 2 braces `@media screen and ((.......)` Use one one bracket
2. You have not closed the media query block

Media query code should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    body {background: #04d056;}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I fixed the code as you indicated but the media queries still don't load on my actual phone/tablet, they only seem to work with google's device simulator :/

Comment: @AndreasS maybe a cache issue at this point?

Comment: That's the weird part, I have deleted the cache in every device I tested it in, it seems to work perfectly in browsers or emulators but not in real devices! You can try it out: bitcoinhub.be , it works perfectly fine until you actually use a mobile browser

Comment: You should always use icongnito or private tabs for testing a website or web page...

Answer (score 0):

You've got:

```
@media screen and ((max-width:1024px) {
```

It should be:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
     //css here
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies! I indeed overlooked that, but the problem still seems to happen? When I use google dev tools the media queries work properly but when I use my phone (Galaxy S5) or my tablet (iPad 2) the green background still doesn't happen? I cleaned my cache and etc.?